# Dynamically create components twice

Tags: jsf, dynamic, jsf-2, components

I'm trying to create via programmcode a HtmlSelectOneMenu. This is not the problem. I realised it like this:

```
final UISelectItem select = (UISelectItem) app.createComponent(UISelectItem.COMPONENT_TYPE);

//Items für DropDownMenü erstellen
List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
for (int k = 0; k < Gender2.values().length; k++){
    items.add(new SelectItem(Gender2.values()[k]));                
}

//Items dem DropDown Menü zuordnen
UISelectItems selectItems = new UISelectItems();
selectItems.setValue(items);
selectOneRadio = (HtmlSelectOneMenu) app.createComponent(HtmlSelectOneMenu.COMPONENT_TYPE);
selectOneRadio.getChildren().add(selectItems);
testgrid.getChildren().add(selectOneRadio);
```

When I call this method again, the following error appears:
Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Komponenten-ID j_idt3:j_id5 was already found

Want can I do against this error?

Comment: When exactly are you invoking this method? Which JSF impl/version exactly are you using?

Comment: I invoke this method <h:commandButton action="#{handler.generateDropDown}" value="DropDown" /> The first time works perfect, but the second time didn't work!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should assign an unique IDs to components that you are creating with `setId()` method.

You can ether generate id's on your own, or use:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().createUniqueId()
```

to generate them.

Comment: Hey partlov, thank you for the fast answer. Now is my problem how to generate unique ID's

Comment: Okay i tried ist with the createUniqueID(), but the erros occurs again. Sommetimes not at the first click, but then when i want to create a new item.

Comment: Okay i got ist. I changed the scope of the bean from session to request and now it works!